# $a_{n+1} = -\sum^{n}_{i=0} \frac{a_{n-1}}{(i+2)!}$ and $a_0=1$. Solve for $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$a_{n+1} = -\sum^{n}_{i=0} \frac{a_{n-1}}{(i+2)!}$ and $a_0=1$. Solve for $a_n$.

This is similar to the form of a taylor series, so I'm thinking that there might be some manipulations I can do to transform it into a recognizable taylor series. However, I can't find anything to make progress.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you worked out the first few values and seen a pattern?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $a_{n-i}$ rather than $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: I think @quasi is right, you have a typo. Once it's fixed, one approach is to consider the generating function $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ and find what the original recurrence means for that function. This should help you solve for what this function is, and from there you can go back to the value of $a_n$.